# Python find message queue id, like EC999DLLK5

Tags: python

Hello :)

I need to find in the line a group of 10 chars like `'EC999DLLK5'`. Line looks like:

```
Oct  2 03:29:46 server postfix/qmgr[2901]: EC999DLLK5: from=<mail_address>, size=876, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

How can I specify a pattern like `EC999DLLK5`?

I mean , lines contain 11 random characters in random order.
So it can be:

```
CCB29415C7
E3043414F0
E75D54127C
013F140FE3
```

etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you give us some more lines?

Comment: What do you mean *"like `'EC999DLLK5'`"*? Always ten characters? Same pattern of numbers and uppercase letters? Always starts with e.g. `'EC9'`? And what do you mean by *"find"*? Do you need the index, or just the matching "word"? You should probably look into regex: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

I made an assumption about what pattern you are looking for. The regex below looks for the pattern: 2 capital letters, 3 numbers, 4 capital letters, 1 number.

```
import re

s = 'Oct  2 03:29:46 server postfix/qmgr[2901]: EC999DLLK5: from=<mail_address>, size=876, nrcpt=1'

re.findall('[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{4}[0-9]', s)
```

Output

```
['EC999DLLK5']
```

If this is not the pattern you are looking for, please give more examples or a better description.